# TomEE taking lot of time while initializing virtual directory

Tags: app-startup

We are using Apache TomEE plus 8 on Windows 2016 Server. We have created a Virtual Directory containing 300K+ files. **It was observed that TomEE taking more than an hour to get started**. TomEE getting started in around 2 minutes if Virtual directory is removed.

Through the virtual directory, we wanted to provide access to report files to the users. https://MYHOST.com/MYREPORTS/pdfreports/pdffile1.pdf

We have used following MYREPORTS.xml under Catalina/conf/localhost/ folder

```
<pre>
<Context docBase="d:\MyFiles\MyReports">
<Resources allowLinking="false" />
</Context>
</pre>
```

**Note**: Folder d:\MyFiles\MyReports has "pdfreports" subfolder, but "pdfreports" is a soft link to network share location.

Not sure what is missing here. Tried to get more logging information but not getting clues. Please share your thoughts. When we checked, TomEE is busy on the following thread stack trace during startup. Seems it is scanning all files in the directory and it must be taking time in scanning all 300K+ files :-(.

```
<pre>
"localhost-startStop-1" - Thread t@50
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(Native Method)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:849)
at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.scanDir(AnnotationFinder.java:213)
at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.scanDir(AnnotationFinder.java:218)
at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.file(AnnotationFinder.java:204)
at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:133)
at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:112)
at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.checkAnnotations(DeploymentLoader.java:2050)
at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.discoverModuleType(DeploymentLoader.java:1971)
at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.discoverModuleType(DeploymentLoader.java:1905)
at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:151)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2303)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1188)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
</pre>
```

Comment: Looking at the source code http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/openejb/util/AnnotationFinder.java.html
it is clear that TomEE is checking all files for Annotations
<pre>
 private void scanDir(File dir, List<String> classNames, String packageName) {
     File[] files = dir.listFiles();
     for (File file : files) {
       if (file.isDirectory()) {
          scanDir(file, classNames, packageName + file.getName() + ".");
       } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
         ..........
 </pre>

Comment: docBase is not meant to provide access to a shared folder. docBase is "The Document Base (also known as the Context Root) directory for this web application". You are telling TomEE "here is the application!" and it interpretes any file to be part of a webapp. 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html
Instead you could just write a small Service that runs on TomEE and provides access to those files.